# Working code but pycharm marks tmF and tmR in list as "local variable referenced before assignment", why is this?

Tags: python, pycharm, local-variables

I've only recently started programming so there may be a simple answer to this question but I couldn't find it on here. My code works fine for what I want to do but as I am new to this I want to get into the practice of writing good readable code. I am using PyCharm and I noticed it marked some of the code below as not defined. I understand a little about global vs local variables and I guess it has something to do with this but I can't work out why this part of the code works at all if this is the case.

```
if len(primerF) < 14:
    tmF = (no_A_F + no_T_F) * 2 + (no_C_F + no_G_F) * 4
    float_tmF = float(tmF)
    print("Forward primer tm: " + str(float_tmF))

elif len(primerR) > 13:
    tmR = 64.9 + 41*(no_C_R + no_G_R - 16.4) / (no_A_R + no_T_R + no_G_R + 
    no_C_R)
    print("Reverse primer tm: " + str(tmR))

if len(primerR) < 14:
    tmR = (no_A_R + no_T_R) * 2 + (no_C_R + no_G_R) * 4
    print("Reverse primer tm: " + str(tmR))

elif len(primerR) > 13:
    tmR = 64.9 + 41*(no_C_R + no_G_R - 16.4) / (no_A_R + no_T_R + no_G_R + 
    no_C_R)
    print("Reverse primer tm: " + str(tmR))

gc_F = (no_G_F + no_C_F)
gc_content_F = float(gc_F) / forward_length * 100
print("Forward GC content: " + str(gc_content_F) + "%")

gc__R = (no_G_R + no_C_R)
gc_content_R = float(gc__R) / reverse_length * 100
print("Reverse GC content: " + str(gc_content_R) + "%")
```

This block here is marked as name not defined and if I click on the bubble it says: "This inspection warns about local variables referenced before assignment".

```
list_tm = [**tmF**, **tmR**]
high_tm = max(list_tm)
low_tm = min(list_tm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `tmF` and `tmR` in conditional blocks that do not cover all possibilities.  For example, if `primerF` is >= 14, `tmF` will never be set before the `list_tm = [tmF, tmR]` statement.  This will result in a runtime error, which pycharm is warning you about.

One way to fix this is to set default values of `tmF` and `tmR` at the top of your code, or to have full conditional coverage by setting `tmF` and `tmR` in `else` (not just `elif`) blocks.

Comment: Thank-you! I set the tmF and tmR in else blocks and it works perfectly now!